# Rabbeinu Asher ben Yeḥiel's nickname(s)

Tags: names, historical-figures, rabbeinu-asher

[Rabbi Asher ben Yeḥiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel), is usually called "Rabbeinu Asher" or "The רא"ש" (pronounced by most Israelis as "Rosh"; often in North America it is pronounced like the English word "rush"*).  However, today I've stumbled across two unsourced internet references to him that call him "Asheri".  How widely used is this nickname, and are there any others?

Also: How is the nickname "Asheri" used? Does it stand alone, or is it "Rav Asheri" or "HaAsheri" ("The Asheri"), or some other formulation?

<sub>*Not to be confused with [Rabbi Shimshon, aka the ר"ש](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens), whose name is often pronounced similarly.</sub>

Comment: Asheri is usually the glosses printed in the Rosh in the Vilna Talmud http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%99

Comment: @DoubleAA, ah, yes, I've seen that. Does anyone else refer to him as that, though?

Comment: (Who is 'him' in your last comment?)

Comment: They probably meant Hagos Ashrei which doubleaa mentioned ,he wrote on the Rosh and was not the Rosh himself.

Comment: So is my first comment the answer? What do you mean in your first comment?

Comment: Just for the record: the "Rush" ר"ש and the "Rosh" רא"ש were 2 different Rishonim. The former wrote a Peirush on the Mishna and can be found at the back of your first and last volume of Shas; on Seder Zeraim and Taharot.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, in my experience most people pronounce Rabbi Shimshon's name with a Pataḥ under the Reish, so it comes out like Räsh, as opposed to Rabbeinu Asher's name, which is pronounced with a Kametz and sounds more like Rɵsh. But thank you for your comment; see my edit.

Comment: @DoubleAA, sorry, we may have misunderstood each other. I guess either my question to you is, "Is that name given to him, or is it a name for the gloss itself? I assume the former, but is that right, and if so, is this unique in this instance or is it but one example?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name האשר"י is used for the Rosh by early Ashkenazi poskim, like the מרדכי, תרומת הדשן, רמ"א & מהרש"ל hundreds or thousands of times. See e.g., [Maharam Schiff](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21161&hilite=ba52aa7e-1b14-4a66-92eb-d9e0be39f7e2&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Maharsha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37964&hilite=9b8885e1-6502-46df-a572-f8c1585472bc&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Mizrachi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1233&hilite=3cbea420-7afc-4659-a0ed-51c1502639b9&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), Rema [Toras Chatas](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37910&hilite=c6c6d067-7da5-4b23-b6d7-24172505e36c&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99) and [Darkei Moshe](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37205&hilite=544e09ba-5f81-47cc-bd0d-2347124e94bf&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Maharam Alashkar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1168&hilite=18f9da3c-e0d7-4168-ad30-680ee8d71083&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Maharshal](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43034&hilite=6c3e656d-5278-4d93-bba8-8c4d6d18417a&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Mahari Weil](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1746&hilite=385e5702-057c-4c8b-8491-6ee7f61c9606&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), [Sha'arei Dura](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9035&hilite=ec4a3c36-0758-4f7b-9452-f89b3b334580&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99) and [Bach](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=651&hilite=4ac44157-0c93-46fc-9c9c-d47047d0b115&st=%D7%94%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%22%D7%99), to name a few.

Comment: Can you link to a few instances?

Comment: A quick Bar Ilan search for האשר"י will do the trick. See also http://www.bhol.co.il/forum/topic.asp?topic_id=2958423&forum_id=19616

Comment: Is the Ashri the Rosh or the notes in the rosh?

Comment: It is the Rosh. Hagahot Ashri is the hagahot ashri--i.e., the notes on the Rosh.

Comment: That forum is interesting, but the first few posts don't point to any instances of its use. Got anything more concrete, or do I have to keep reading the thread?

Comment: Okay, I added some links.